# Swift iOS Programmatically RTL the layout of my App

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an app that would allow users to select 2 languags, English and Arabic.

So when the user selects Arabic, i want my app to have a RTL layout.

Question is how would i do that? I've tried doing it this way: `Settings>General>Language Region` . If I select Saudi Arabia as the Region, and select Arabic as the Language, my app automatically does RTL.

As you can see that method is through Phone Settings and affects your Phone's overall layout.

Now, what i really want to accomplish is just to make my APP RTL without going to `Settings>General>Language Region` and affect my Phone's layout. So when i click the button in my app "Arabic", my App will change its layout into RTL.

Any help please, your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you implementing an in-app language chooser? This will be confusing to your users as they expect all apps to follow the configuration in the Settings app–not some thing of your own.

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid doing this. In-app language switchers are a confusing experience as your users expect their apps to follow the configuration in the Settings app–not some thing of your own.

Contrary to some answers here, your layout will *not* automatically become right-to-left if you choose to go down this path, and you will also run into issues like any number or date formatters you're using, and any system UI you present (like UIActivityViewController) will also not follow this override.

You should instead stick to using as much of the API as possible–UIKit, NSLocalizedString and Auto Layout make it seamless for you to follow the system UI language without having to resort to undocumented hacks on NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

To add right to left support refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to build your own mechanism here. as you wanted button to change your language. Im using following code on my views:

```
+ (BOOL)isEnglishLanguage
{
    return !language;
}

+ (void)setLanguage:(Language)lang
{
    language = lang;
    [GeneralUtilities storeObjectInUserDefaults:@(language) WithKey:@"language"];
}

+ (NSString *)currentLanguage
{
    if(language == ENGLISH)
    {
        return kLanguageEnglish;
    }
    else if(language == ARABIC)
    {
        return kLanguageArabic;
    }
    return @"";
}

+ (NSString *) NSLocalizedStringCustom:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path;
    if([[LanguageUtilities currentLanguage] isEqualToString:kLanguageEnglish])
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kLanguageEnglish ofType:@"lproj"];
    else if([[LanguageUtilities currentLanguage] isEqualToString:kLanguageArabic])
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kLanguageArabic ofType:@"lproj"];

    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}

+ (NSTextAlignment) NSLocalizedTextFieldAllingment
{
    if([[LanguageUtilities currentLanguage] isEqualToString:kLanguageEnglish])
        return NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    else if([[LanguageUtilities currentLanguage] isEqualToString:kLanguageArabic])
        return NSTextAlignmentRight;
    else  return NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}
```

i hope it will work for you too.

Comment: This will unfortunately not work for RTL UI nor will it work for any formatters or system UI presented by the app.